# GWT: removing proxy from RequestContext?

Tags: gwt2, requestfactory

Let's assume following scenario. There is a collection of `Animals` in the `Zoo`. User may add and/or remove animals to the `Zoo` and when he is ready, he can hit save to send request.

We are handling adding new animal using:

```
AnimalProxy animal = saveRequest.create(AnimalProxy.class);
animal.setZoo(zoo);
zoo.getAnimals(animal);
...
```

But what if user changes his mind and decide to remove animal he just created/added from zoo before saving?

Because this animal is already managed by `saveRequest` we would need to somehow unbind it from `saveRequest` (so that this animal won't be send to server). But `RequestContext` interface offers only methods for *adding* proxies to it (`edit()` and `create()`), but there is no single method of removing proxies. Any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my question was just accepting the fact that canceled `AnimalProxy` were sent to server but making sure that it **will not be persisted** on server side. There is probably no way to remove proxy from `RequestContext` at the moment.